# php sql, paste equal rows, and order from largest

Tags: php, sql

I have a table sorted like this, example;

```
name | like
_______________
mark   8
luca   8
giorge 2
delta  3
delta  2
luca   8
mark   3
```

now I would like;
1 merge results name
2 and then sort, after joining the result from largest to smallest, example;

```
    name | like
    _______________
    luca   16
    mark   11
    delta  5
    giorge 2
```

how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

simple group by :

```
select 
  name, sum(like) as likecount
from tablename
group by name
order by likecount desc
```